# Uniform integrability of a set of measurable functions (show an equivalence)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, uniform-integrability

We call a set $\mathcal{F}$ of measurable functions uniformly integrable if for any $\varepsilon >0$ it exists a non-negative, integrable function $h$ so that
$$
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int 1_{\left\{\lvert f\rvert\geq h\right\}}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon.~~~~~~(*)
$$
Now the task is to show the following:

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal{F}$ a set of measurable functions. Show, that $\mathcal{F}$ is equi-integrable exactly when for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an integrable function $h\geq 0$ so that
> >     $$
> > \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int (\lvert f\rvert-h)^+\, d\mu\leq\varepsilon.
> > $$

Here is how I would prove it.

"$\Longrightarrow$": Consider any $\varepsilon >0, f\in\mathcal{F}$. It is
$$
(\lvert f\rvert -h)^+\leq 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq h}\lvert f\rvert
$$
and therefore
$$
\int (\lvert f\rvert-h)^+\, d\mu\leq\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq h}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$
Because the right side does not depend on $f$, it is
$$
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int (\lvert f\rvert-h)^+\, d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$

"$\Longleftarrow$": Consider any $\varepsilon > 0$. It exists a $h_{\varepsilon/2}\geq 0$, $h_{\varepsilon/2}$ integrable with
$$
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int (\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+\, d\mu<\varepsilon/2.~~~~~(+)
$$
Define 
$$
k:=2h_{\varepsilon/2}.
$$
For any$f\in\mathcal{F}$ it is with the $\Delta$-inequation
$$
\lvert f\rvert\leq\lvert\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2}\rvert+\lvert h_{\varepsilon/2}\rvert=\lvert\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2}\rvert+h_{\varepsilon/2}.
$$
Because of 
$$
(\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+=\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2}
$$
for $\lvert f\rvert \geq k$, i.e. especially $\lvert f\rvert\geq h_{\varepsilon/2}$, it is
$$
1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}\lvert f\rvert\leq 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}((\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^++h_{\varepsilon/2})
$$
and therefore
$$
\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu\leq\int1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}(\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+\, d\mu+\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}h_{\varepsilon/2}\, d\mu.
$$
It is
$$
1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}(\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+\leq (\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+
$$
and because of $(+)$  it follows that
$$
\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}(\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+\, d\mu<\varepsilon/2
$$
and because of
$$
1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}h_{\varepsilon/2}\leq 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}(\lvert f\rvert-h_{\varepsilon/2})^+
$$
it is in the same way
$$
\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k} h_{\varepsilon/2}\, d\mu < \varepsilon /2,
$$
what means that
$$
\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon.
$$
Because the right side does not depend on $f$, it follows that
$$
\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\geq k}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\varepsilon,
$$
i.e. a function $h$ is found which fullfills the definition, namely $k$.

That's it. Could anybody say me, if my proof is allright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof looks correct. Maybe it can be shortened a little, skipping some estimates like $|f|\leqslant |f-h|+|h|\color{blue}{=|f-h|+h}$ since$h$ is non-negative.

Comment: You are right, maybe it is too detailed here and there.Anyhow, I am always satisfied when I managed it to write my thoughts down in a comprehensible (but maybe too long) way.

Comment: I agree. It's easier for the reader to skip a step, but hard to fill a potential gap.